# How to start elasticsearch run as service in centos 7?

Tags: elasticsearch, service, centos

I have install elasticsearch 2.3.3 in centos 7 but after closing terminal elasticsearch plugin head automatically close but I want keep running in background. please give me helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in background as two ways,

```
1. Nohup 
2. Creating service script and put it in init.d folder
```

Nohup

**Eg:** nohup ./bin/elasticsearch

Service script

Use the following script,

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          Elasticsearch
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Runs elasticsearch daemon
# Description: Runs the elasticsearch daemon as a non-root user
### END INIT INFO

# Process name
NAME=elasticsearch
DESC="Elasticsearch"
PROG="/etc/init.d/elasticsearch"

# Configure location of Elasticsearch bin
ELASTICSEARCH_BIN=/opt/elasticsearch-2.3.0/bin

# PID Info
PID_FOLDER=/var/run/elasticsearch/
PID_FILE=/var/run/elasticsearch/$NAME.pid
LOCK_FILE=/var/lock/subsys/$NAME
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$ELASTICSEARCH_BIN
DAEMON=$ELASTICSEARCH_BIN/$NAME

# Configure logging location
ELASTICSEARCH_LOG=/var/log/elasticsearch.log

# Begin Script
RETVAL=0

if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "You need root privileges to run this script"
        exit 1
fi

# Function library
. /etc/init.d/functions

start() {
        echo -n "Starting $DESC : "

        pid=`pidofproc -p $PID_FILE elasticsearch`
        if [ -n "$pid" ] ; then
                echo "Already running."
                exit 0
        else
        # Start Daemon
                if [ ! -d "$PID_FOLDER" ] ; then
                        mkdir $PID_FOLDER
                fi
                daemon --user=$DAEMON_USER --pidfile=$PID_FILE $DAEMON 1>"$ELASTICSEARCH_LOG" 2>&1 &
                sleep 2
                pidofproc node > $PID_FILE
                RETVAL=$?
                [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && success || failure
                echo
                [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch $LOCK_FILE
                return $RETVAL
        fi
}

reload()
{
    echo "Reload command is not implemented for this service."
    return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC : "
        killproc -p $PID_FILE $DAEMON
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f $PID_FILE $LOCK_FILE
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  status)
        status -p $PID_FILE $DAEMON
        RETVAL=$?
        ;;
  restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
  reload)
        reload
        ;;
  *)
        # Invalid Arguments, print the following message.
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}" >&2
        exit 2
        ;;
esac
```

sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/elasticsearch
sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 96 9

sudo /etc/init.d/elasticsearch restart

Comment: are there any disadvantages to running it using nohup?

Comment: @user3494047 Yes it is. If you rebooted server nohup wont run.